# Include SPen SDK Library in Android app

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk

When using an app that depends on the SPen SDK library, why must the user download the SPen SDK from the Google Play store first? Can't the SDK be included in the original app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=274713&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=2&searchType=ALL&searchText=pen+sdk) answers the question I think.

Answer (score 0):

This must be something new. I don't remember that being the case when I played with it. Also, are you sure it's making you download it from Google Play and not from its own Samsung app store.

That being said, I can see a reason for doing that. By making the SDK library an application, Samsung can update the library code much more easily when it needs to change (instead of relying on the third party developer to do it).

I suppose Samsung could embed the library in its own custom ROM instead, but that update mechanism too would be at the mercy of the carriers.

Comment: Yep here's the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.sdk.spen30&hl=en) to download the sdk from the play store. If you try to download an app like [Post Memo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.kmemo&hl=en), you must download the Pen SDK first. 

I think you are probably right. Samsung just wants to make it easier to update the library. Thanks